# Errors object required in invoking Spring validation

Tags: spring, validation

I am working on a application using spring. i want to use spring validation framework for validating different domain/model objects from the service layer which has the validator injected. I am planning to use ValidationUtils to invoke validator, but i am not sure what implementation of errors i need to pass to the invokeValidator method.

Signature in ValidationUtils:

```
  invokeValidator(Validator validator, Object obj, Errors errors)
```

Will it be right to use  BeanPropertyBindingResult.

```
  BeanPropertyBindingResult result = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(javaProduct, "javaProduct");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ofcourse. You can pass object of **BeanPropertyBindingResult** object to the Errors.

It is implements the interface **Errors**.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.